# XCode: select/replace multiple words in current working file?

Tags: xcode, sublimetext3

Does the XCode IDE have the ability to make multiple, simultaneous selections of a word within the file you have open (not the whole project) and then replace it with new text? And, I don't necessarily want to select all occurrences, say just the first 3 of 5 or whatever.

Basically, I'm coming from the wonderful world of Sublime Text, and in Sublime you can select any word, then simply press CMD+D and it will sequentially find then select subsequent findings of this word. Most importantly after you select the word multiple times, just by typing you will be replacing **each selected word** so you only have to type once.

The following question is the same as mine except that it's asking for a different IDE (Eclipse): [eclipse multiple text selection like sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583201/eclipse-multiple-text-selection-like-sublime-text-2)

Any way to do this using XCode 7beta or XCode 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that feeling coming from Sublime ^^
Look at this thread, they give some nice advices:
[Multiple cursors / highlight next instance of currently highlighted word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881824/multiple-cursors-highlight-next-instance-of-currently-highlighted-word)

Especially this link:
http://sohailk.com/posts/project-three.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you'll be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on all posts. If a question seems to be a duplicate, then flag it as such.

Comment: @MattDMo apologies for posting a dupe question--I actually tried searching extensively and I just couldn't find the specific question I was asking for XCode vs. Sublime...maybe the words I was searching for were off. In any case, glad to have found an answer

Comment: @MattDMo noted, thanks for the help.